# Why won't TS say "This condition will always return 'false'" when comparing a string to a null?

Tags: typescript

If you compare a string to a number you get a never and a warning
[image]

Why there's no such warning if you compare a string to a null/undefined? The `smth` is still narrowed to never in that case, but there's no warning.

- strictNullChecks is on
- string is obviously just an example of a type that doesn't include null/undefined
- I guess the answer should be [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#null-and-undefined), but I can't figure it out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was actually like that for a short time, but they removed it. The reasoning is:

You might be using typescript to build a library. That library could be consumed by a plain js project or a project without strict null checks. For that reason you may still want null check is your code. Not for your own code, but for the code of a different project that uses it.

Here is the corresponding pull request with the reasoning for it:

https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/8452

As far a I could find out, there are no ts config options to get the behavior you want.

A side note:

You might say, that checking for `111` should also be valid in that case, because if another project calls the method you could pass that. For that reason `typeof` check are also always allowed, even if it does not make sense inside your project:

```js
function test(a: string) {
  // ensure a is actually a valid string
  if (a == null || typeof a !== 'string') {
    console.error("illegal argument");
    return;
  }
  console.log(a); 
}

test("a");
test(123 as any);
test(null as any);
```